# How do I deploy lower environments in Azure with Microservices architecture?

Tags: azure, microservices

I have a microservice-oriented Web App running in Azure, and currently we have to deploy each service individually to our lower environments, which leads to lots of manual tasks and headaches. Is there a way to simply replicate all of my microservices to a lower environment easily? (Like I was able to do with [Deployment Slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) on a Web App when we used N-Tier Architecture?)

I've researched [Azure Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/), which seems to require me to put everything in one solution (which I don't really want to do)

We're also already using Azure Devops for [automating deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2), but it seems like I have to already have the lower environment set up in order to release or build to it.

I'd like to be able to do the equivalent of containing everything in a resource group and replicating that as a fully functioning lower environment.

Comment: What do you mean with *lower environments*?

Comment: A lower environment for me would be a deployed version of the web app that could be used by developers or qa to test out changes before the changes go to production. Usually you can have separate config files for lower environments so that you can turn off certain features like emailing customers.